# Xamarin.IOS not displaying image from USB webcam frame

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage

My Windows UWP project reads and displays each frame from a USB webcam, and then it sends it by TCP socket to my IPAD running my Xamarin.IOS app.

But they don't display in the iPAD UIImage control.
(If I programmatically set the UIImage to a .jpg then that displays ok)

Here is the code that reads each camera frame from a USB camera...

```
void FrameReader_FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
{
    // TryAcquireLatestFrame will return the latest frame that has not yet been acquired.
    // This can return null if there is no such frame, or if the reader is not in the
    // "Started" state. The latter can occur if a FrameArrived event was in flight
    // when the reader was stopped.
    using (var frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame())
    {
        if (frame != null)
        {
            var renderer = _frameRenderers[frame.SourceKind];
            renderer.ProcessFrame(frame);
            …

            public void ProcessFrame( MediaFrameReference frame){

                softwareBitmap = FrameRenderer.ConvertToDisplayableImage(frame?.VideoMediaFrame);

                SoftwareBitmap latest_frame_SoftwareBitmap;

                var imageSource = (SoftwareBitmapSource)_imageElement.Source;
                await imageSource.SetBitmapAsync( latest_frame_SoftwareBitmap);

                latest_frame_SoftwareBitmap.CopyToBuffer( Frames_To_iPad.buffer_to_IOS.AsBuffer

                buffer_to_IOS sent by socket to Xamarin.IOS app running on iPad.


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that is supposed to display each frame within a Xamarin.IOS UIKit.UIImage control...

```
            ImageView_camera.Image =         UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromArray( Camera_Socket_Client.packet_frame_state.buffer ));  // DISPLAYS NOTHING

            // SIMPLE TEST...
            ImageView_camera.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("good_photo_of_Doug.jpg"); // DISPLAYS OK
```

Comment: have you saved saved the buffer data to a file to confirm that it is valid image data?

Comment: That's a good idea. The Windows app actually displays the webcam image without problem.  But saving to file will allow me to track down which format displays in iOS IIMAGE control.

Comment: What file analyzer do you recommend?  I tried File Analyzer but can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: see my comment on your other question

Comment: I see nothing on other question about file analyzer.

Comment: "a quick scan of the MediaFrameReader docs turns up "Because the frames will arrive as SoftwareBitmap objects" which would make think it needs to be converted into a format that iOS supports"